# Differentiability of $x \mapsto \dfrac{x}{\| x \|}$

Tags: derivatives

Let $(E, \| \, \|)$ be a normed vector space, and let $\Phi: E \, \backslash \{ 0_E \} \to E, \, x \mapsto \dfrac{x}{\| x \|}$.

Is $\Phi$ differentiable ? I did try to look at $\Phi(x + h) - \Phi(x)$, but I do not see what to do ...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It depends on the norm. For example, if $\| \cdot \|$ is the $1$-norm on $E = \Bbb{R}^2$, then $\Phi$ is not differentiable at any point along the $x$-axis.

Comment: Great, thank you !